# Is it possible to apply a target audiences in calendar view in SharePoint 2013?

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, calendar, view, audience-targeting

I added a calendar view web part in SharePoint 2013. It is showing all the events in the calendar view.

I need to show the events based on Audience Targeting in the calendar view. Please suggest me a some best practice to achieve this.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can achieve that easily by enabling `Enable audience targeting` as the following:

- List setting > Below general settings >  click Audience targeting settings.

[image]

Once `Audience Targeting` is enabled you will be able to assign target audience for current Event or new event as shown below

[image]

Regarding `I need to show the events based on Audience Targeting in the calendar view.`

Unfortunately, you can't do that in the calendar view. Meanwhile, you can only switch from calendar view to all Events view then Modify your view and filter with or group by as you need with Targeting Audience field.

[image]

For more details check [Target content to specific audiences](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Target-content-to-specific-audiences-33d84cb6-14ed-4e53-a426-74c38ea32293)

Comment: @Qassas Thanks for the kind response, I am struck in showing the events in default calendar view based on audience targeting. I mean Audience Targeting need to applied for entire calendar view

Comment: I mean individual event need to be shown based on audience

Comment: @Suriya please check my updated answer